# NetworkError on XMLHttpRequest.send(ArrayBuffer)

Tags: javascript, php, file-upload, web-worker

I'm working on an upload routine for files with a size of 3gb and more. To do this I'm chunking the file and send each piece with `XMLHttpRequest.send(chunk)` to my server.

I'm using webworkers to make the whole process synchronous so I use `FileReaderSync` too.

My routine works fine for small files however I get an error from time to time in larger files.

The Exception happens on `XMLHttpRequest.send(chunk)`

> NetworkError // at least in IE 11

And my log shows

> *** buffer overflow detected ***: /usr/sbin/apache2 terminated

I'm sending inside my worker like this

```
self.onmessage = function (event)
{
    // create XHR instance
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // send the file through POST
    xhr.open("post", "../upload.php", false); // Sync open file
    xhr.responseType = 'text';
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream; charset=UTF-8");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-INDEX", event.data["index"]); // Chunkindex
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CHUNKS-TOTAL", event.data["maxChunks"]); // Total chunks
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-PSEUDO-NAME", event.data["pseudoName"]); // pseudo name
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CHUNK-SIZE", event.data["size"]); // chunk size

    try {
        xhr.send(event.data["content"]); // here the Exception occurs
    } catch (e)
    {
        self.postMessage('error'); // error case
    }

    self.postMessage(xhr.responseText); // Return answer
};
```

The Backtrace or Memory map in log dont help here and I've no Idea whats going on.

**UPDATE**

The Chunks are read `$inputHandler = fopen('php://input', "r");` and write to file `file_put_contents($target, $inputHandler, FILE_APPEND)`

Comment: This is a server error that doesn't probably have anything to do with your implementation. How do you save the data on server? I'm flagging this question as unclear because the important information is missing.

Comment: This is weird problem, but attempt to solve it would lead to long comment discussion. I created a chat room if you want to try to solve it: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109015/buffer-overflow-apache
 I suggest that we try a different server to save the file to see whether it's Apache problem. After that we might try to use more low-level functions to save the data.

Comment: @TomášZato Thank you but I'll try to disable all modules first etc. if I can find any solution or can't find any I'll tell you